# Is it possible to build a module with -undefined,dynamic_lookup?

Tags: emscripten

I'm trying to build my code as a module with `-s MODULARIZE=1` and I want it to be used as a dynamic shared library.

However, it seems like the `-undefined,dynamic_lookup` flag is not supported in Emscripten.

Without the flag, I'm getting many undefined symbol warnings when I build my code with Emscripten.

Is there any alternative way to build a module without these warnings?

Comment: Please add the sample code, commands to compile, the warnings you're referring to, and any other relevant information for an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).